# SQL result into 3 bucket by count

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
=============================
Itemnumber| Check_ind| year
=============================
123       |Y         | 2011
456       |Y         | 2011
123       |Y         | 2012
456       |Y         | 2011
456       |Y         | 2011
```

I want to result to be

```
=====================
 1|   2-3|    4
=====================
123| 456  |
```

I want to count total time that each itemnumber appear in the table and where year=2011, then  put it into bucket.  my itnitial think was something like :

```
   SELECT case when count(Itemnumber)>=0 and <=1 then '1'
    case when count(Itemnumber)>=2 and <=3 then '2-3'
    else '4' end
   from table where year = '2011'
```

Comment: how would you expect the result to be like if, both 123 and 456 occurs for only one time?

Comment: How do you expect to return ItemNumbers that appear 0 times?  Also, which column do you want counts of 3 to appear in? Both?

Comment: @ChorWaiChun I think the result is correct, since 123 only shows once in the table and where year=2011, so it belong to 0-1 bucket

Comment: @aph thank you for catching my error! so the column will be 1|2-3|4

Comment: What about when you have another ItemNumber for a given column??

Comment: @SeanLange, so depend on how many time this "another itemnumber" appear in the table, it will put it into belonging bucket

Comment: But in your output you have the ItemNumber. What do you actually want for output, the number of ItemNumbers in each bucket?

Comment: @SeanLange so the output will be itemnumber, so if the itemnumber shows up in the table 1 time, the itemnumber will go into the 1 bucket, if the itemnumber shows up 2 times, the itemnumber will go into the 2-3 bucket ect....

Comment: But what is the OUTPUT??? If you have two item numbers in the same bucket what do you want in the result set?

Comment: @SeanLange if there is 2 itemnumber that fall into the same bucket, show both 2 itemnumner ect

Comment: I would highly recommend you read this article before your next post. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Had you presented the information clearly this would have been a lot simpler for everyone, including yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need -

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ( ItemNumber VARCHAR(5)
                   ,Check_Ind CHAR(1)
                   ,YEAR varchar(4)
                  )

INSERT INTO @T VALUES ('123','Y','2011')
                     ,('456','Y','2011')
                     ,('123','Y','2012')
                     ,('456','Y','2011')
                     ,('456','Y','2011')

SELECT * FROM @t


SELECT CASE WHEN Count(ItemNumber) < 2 THEN ItemNumber ELSE '' END [0-1]
    ,CASE  WHEN Count(ItemNumber) BETWEEN 2 AND 3 THEN ItemNumber ELSE '' END [2-3]
    ,CASE WHEN Count(ItemNumber) > 3 THEN ItemNumber ELSE '' END [4]
    FROM @T
    WHERE YEAR = '2011'
    GROUP BY ItemNumber
```

Comment: I like your solution: Works in this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/708df/2 but have lot of nulls.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I just now edited my answer to replace nulls with blank.

Comment: The problem wasn't the nulls. The OP request multiple data in same row. But looks like doesnt really care.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is maybe there is a better solution using pivot.

While someone find that, here is my solution:

- You could handle null with a `case` to show `space` if that is a problem.

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/708df/1)

- I include a few more data in the sample, let me know if that is ok.
- Have to use `FULL JOIN` because I don't know what group will have the most items.

.

```
with item_count AS (
      SELECT itemnumber, count(*) as total
      FROM item 
      WHERE year = '2011'
      GROUP BY itemnumber    
), t_01 AS (
      SELECT itemnumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY itemnumber) AS row_id  
      FROM item_count 
      WHERE total between 0 and 1
 ), t_02 AS (
      SELECT itemnumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY itemnumber) AS row_id  
      FROM item_count 
      WHERE total between 2 and 3
 ), t_03 AS (
      SELECT itemnumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY itemnumber) AS row_id  
      FROM item_count 
      WHERE total = 4
 )
 SELECT t_01.itemnumber as '0-1', t_02.itemnumber as '2-3', t_03.itemnumber as '4'
 from 
    t_01 
    full join t_02 
        on t_01.row_id = t_02.row_id
    full join t_03
        on t_01.row_id = t_03.row_id
```

[image] 
I add item `789` and `999` to the data sample

Comment: Thank you! I am waiting to see if there more easy way for the solution =)

Answer (score 0):

This question is not well defined so I am somewhat making a guess here. Notice I also am posting ddl and sample data in a consumable format. This makes things a lot easier for the people trying to help.

```
create table #Something
(
    Itemnumber int,
    Check_ind char(1),
    MyYear int
)

insert #Something
select 123, 'Y', 2011 union all
select 456, 'Y', 2011 union all
select 123, 'Y', 2012 union all
select 456, 'Y', 2011 union all
select 456, 'Y', 2011

--Now add another group for the "2-3" bucket
insert #Something
select 12, 'Y', 2011 union all
select 12, 'Y', 2011;

with GroupSubtotals as
(
    select case when COUNT(ItemNumber) < 2 then 1 end as [0-1]
        , case when COUNT(ItemNumber) > 1 and COUNT(ItemNumber) < 4 then 1 end as [2-3]
        , case when COUNT(ItemNumber) > 3 then 1 end as [4]
    from #Something s
    where s.MyYear = 2011
    group by ItemNumber
)

select SUM([0-1]) as [0-1]
    , SUM([2-3]) as [2-3]
    , SUM([4]) as [4]
from GroupSubtotals
```

Comment: OP what the item `name` on the result, not the `count`.

Comment: We don't know that because they never clarified. We are both making assumptions because the question is too vague.

Comment: I know the question isnt too good. but the table output `I want to result to be` show item number very clear.

Comment: Yes and when asked for clarity only vagueness was returned again.